I flip a coin 10 times. What is the expected number of pairs of consecutive tosses that come up heads?
For example, the sequences $THHTHHHTHH$ has 4 pairs of consecutive HH's.
I question the approach of a solution in my textbook. It goes as such: There are $2^{10}=1024$ possible sequences of ten coin flips. We know that $2^8=256$ of them begin with HH (since we have 2 choices for each of the remaining 8 flips). Similarly, for any particular choice of consecutive flips, we know that 256 of the sequences have HH in that position. Thus, there are $9(256)$ total consecutive pairs of heads among the 1024 sequences, and hence the EV for the number of consecutive pairs of heads in any sequences is $$\dfrac{9(256)}{1024} = 9(\dfrac{1}{4}) = \dfrac{9}{4}$$
My issue with this approach is that it overcounts the sequences in the numerator. For example, $HHHTTTTTTT$ is counted for twice when considering the 256 sequences that begin with HH and the 256 sequences that have HH in the second position.
Why is it that even with overcounting, the answer above is correct?

This is "linearity of expectation" in action: there are $9$ places where HH can occur, and it has probability $\frac14$ of happening in each place.  It would not work so simply if you did not count overlapping HHs.

@Henry I thought about this a little more, it looks like I was confusing counting the total number of valid outcomes versus adding up the expectation of individual events. I propose this new solution, please let me know if it makes sense.
Let $Y$ be the random variable that counts the number of consecutive heads in a 10 coin flips. We are looking for $E[Y]$. Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable that denotes whether there are a pair of heads at position $i$, where $1\leq i \leq 9$ (with value 1 if there is a pair of heads at position $i$, 0 otherwise). We see that $Y = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_9$. Now by linearity of expectation, $E[Y] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] + \ldots + E[X_9]$. And clearly $E[X_1] = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4} = E[X_i]$. Thus $E[Y] = 9(\frac{1}{4}) = \frac{9}{4} \square$.

Yes, that is a nice way to find the expectation you are after and agrees with the contents of the comment of @Henry.
